# When are presheaves models of multi-sorted Lawvere theories?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra, monoid, monads

As I understand it there is a correspondence between [finitary monads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finitary+monad) and single-sorted (ordinary) Lawvere theories. My first question is, for a monoid $M$ in Set, when will it be the case that the corresponding [action monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+monad) is finitary ?

As I understand it, when this action monad is finitary the following categories will be equivalent:

- The category of models of $L$ in Set, where $L$ is the Lawvere theory corresponding to the action monad of $M.$
- The category of algebras of the action monad of $M.$
- The category of functors from $M$ to Set.

So in this case we can find a single-sorted Lawvere theory that has models corresponding to [copresheaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copresheaf) of $M$ (presuming I haven't misunderstood).

So my second question is, when can I do this for a more general category, instead of just a monoid ? In particular, given a category $\mathcal{C},$ when can I find a [multi-sorted Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/multisorted+Lawvere+theories) $L$ such that the models of $L$ correspond to functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to Set ?

Comment: It seems to me that the monad $X\mapsto M\times X$ is not only finitary for every monoid $M$, but alsTo cocontinuous: the functor $M\times -$ commutes with all colimits, because it's a left adjoint (to the functor $\hom(M,-)$). The category of algebras for the monad $M\times -$ is precisely the category of $M$-sets, realising the equivalences you mention. Your second question seems a little bit different from this perspective...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an algebraic theory $L : \mathbb F \to \mathscr L$, the category of models of $L$ is given by $\mathbf{Sind}(\mathscr L)$ the cocompletion of $\mathscr L$ under [sifted colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sifted+colimit). The presheaf construction on a small category $\mathscr C$ can be exhibited by first cocompleting it under finite coproducts $\mathbf{Fam}(\mathscr C)$ and then by cocompleting this category under sifted colimits, i.e. $\mathbf{Sind}(\mathbf{Fam}(\mathscr C))$. Therefore, the category of presheaves on a category $\mathscr C$ is always the category of models of an algebraic theory: namely, of the identity functor on $\mathbf{Fam}(\mathscr C)$.